# Excel (how to use if then else for the following condition)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-statements

```
cell 1>cell 2,cell 1<cell 4 print the value in cell 3
cell 1<cell 2,cell 1<cell 4 print the value in cell 4
cell 1>cell 2,cell 3<cell 2 print the value in cell 2
```

how to use these three condition in a single cell in excel

```
=IF(AND((E27>F27,E27<H27),G27),IF((E27<F27,E27<H27),H27),IF((E27>F27,G27<F27),F27),0)
```

its not working can some one please help me out in this

Comment: I believe that you misplaced some of the brackets. This statement has no errors, but I don't know if it will give you the correct response. "=IF(AND(E27>F27, E27<H27), G27, IF(AND(E27<F27, E27<H27), H27, IF(AND(E27>F27, G27<F27), F27, 0)))"

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `IF` and `AND` conditions wrongly

### Syntax:

`IF` Syntax is as follows,

```
IF(Condition, "True", "False")
```

`AND` Syntax is as follows,

```
AND(Condition1, Condition2, ...)
```

Hence your formula should be

```
 =IF(AND(A1>B1,A1<D1), C1, IF(AND(A1<B1, A1<D1), D1, IF(AND(A1>B1,C1<B1), B1, "Not Applicable")))
                                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                                          It can be ZERO, as per your formula
```